# controll bitmap image manually

Tags: android, eclipse

I,m taking my first step into movement of bitmaps. From bits on the internet i,ve created this simple code. The bitmap moves across the screen from top left to top right it goes off the screen and back on at 0,0. What i want to do is add a button or method to manually move the image. I,m only using this single class and have noticed it does not use the main_activity xml Or does it?? If someone could show me on this 1 direction i can duplicate for the other directions. If youd like to add code so doesnt go off screen would be a bonus

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {    
int x=0;
int y=0;
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(new myView(this));  }

private class myView extends View{
public myView(Context context) {
super(context);  }

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {   
Bitmap myBitmap =    BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),  R.drawable.richinch);

if (x < canvas.getWidth()){x +=10;}
else {x=0;}   
    canvas.drawBitmap(myBitmap, x, y, null);

       invalidate();

  }}}
```

Ive added this to the code and read a little on OnTouch listener. How would i add that to the region or Rectangle this would be very helpfull so effectively i,m using the Bitmap as a button if was button id know with onclick, Basicall im trying to make 2 Bitmap buttons to move the image Left Right for now.Eventually all directions. Please use names im using unless creating summit eg int etc

```
 Paint green = new Paint();
 green.setColor(Color.RED);
 green.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
 ////creating the shape////         
 Rect rect= new Rect();
 rect.set(0, 0,x+50, x+50);
 canvas.drawRect(rect,green);
 Region region = new Region(0, 950, 100, 1030);
```

Comment: you could have a custom layout. have a linear layout or relative layout in the custom layout and add the view `myView` to your layout. You can have buttons also in your custom layout

Comment: can you explain this in a bit of detail. how do i make a custom layout do i put a layout in main XML or create a new XML. If so how would i call that layer into my main activity

Answer (score 0):

I am not exactly sure what you want to achieve, but if you would like to make an animation, avoid using onDraw() and just let [ObjectAnimator](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/ObjectAnimator.html) do the "moving" for you. Here's a [detailed tutorial](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/prop-animation.html) on it.

The minimum code you need:

```
ObjectAnimator animation = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(yourObject, "x", xDest);
animation.setDuration(500); // milliseconds
animation.start();
```

Comment: So how would i use this within my code and will this allow me to add the button

Comment: Just pass on an object that needs to be animated (yourObject). Wrap these 3 lines into a void method and call it when you need it.

Answer (score 0):

You are not using any xml

this part here:
setContentView(new myView(this)); is where you would add your xml file setContentView(R.layout.mainxml)

If you want to move around a bitmap with the touch of your finger check out these tutorials. They do exactly this and you will learn to use a SurfaceView

http://www.eis4u.com/2012/02/13/playing-with-graphics-in-android-part-i/
http://www.eis4u.com/2012/02/13/playing-with-graphics-in-android-part-ii/
http://www.eis4u.com/2012/02/13/playing-with-graphics-in-android-part-iii/

Comment: I looked at that its good and ill keep it for my next lesson. All im learning at moment is how to move the bitmaps myself with buttons bitmaps or region and Ontouch those are the words popping out from my research